# How to prevent race conditions when performing one-to-one multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am working on a program that will return a vector containing the number of factors for each number in a text file that is provided.

```
void thrMain(const std::vector<long>& list, std::vector<int>& result,
    const int startInd, const int endInd) {
    for (int i = startInd; (i < endInd); i++) {
       result[i] = countFactors(list[i]);
    }
}
```

This method splits the list into sections for the threads to operate on.

```
std::vector<int> getFactorCount(const std::vector<long>& numList, const int thrCount) {
   // Create a list of threads
   std::vector<std::thread> thrList;
   // List of factor counts in each thread
   std::vector<int> countF(thrCount);
   // What each thread should work on
   const int thrCounter = (numList.size() / thrCount) + 1;
   // Thread work
   for (int i = 0, start = 0; (i < thrCounter); i++, start += thrCounter) {
       int end = std::min<int>(start + thrCounter, numList.size());
       thrList.push_back(std::thread(thrMain, std::ref(numList),
            std::ref(countF), start, end));
   }
   // Join threads together once they finish
   for (auto& t : thrList) {
       t.join();
   }
   return countF;
}
```

The error that I get

```
==4100441==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000074 at pc 0x561fb6172859 bp 0x7f5d13c05bc0 sp 0x7f5d13c05bb0
WRITE of size 4 at 0x602000000074 thread T2
    #0 0x561fb6172858 in thrMain(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int) /home/blackemr/cse381/exercise8_part2/exercise8_part2.cpp:27
    #1 0x561fb617c48b in void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int), std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const>, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int, int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int), std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const>&&, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&&, int&&, int&&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/invoke.h:60
    #2 0x561fb617c236 in std::__invoke_result<void (*)(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int), std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const>, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int, int>::type std::__invoke<void (*)(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int), std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const>, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int, int>(void (*&&)(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int), std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const>&&, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&&, int&&, int&&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/invoke.h:95
    #3 0x561fb617c036 in void std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int), std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const>, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int, int> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul, 2ul, 3ul, 4ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul, 2ul, 3ul, 4ul>) /usr/include/c++/9/thread:244
    #4 0x561fb617bf4f in std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int), std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const>, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int, int> >::operator()() /usr/include/c++/9/thread:251
    #5 0x561fb617beb7 in std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int), std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const>, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int, int> > >::_M_run() /usr/include/c++/9/thread:195
    #6 0x7f5d173e4cb3  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0xd6cb3)
    #7 0x7f5d174f8608 in start_thread /build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/nptl/pthread_create.c:477
    #8 0x7f5d17223102 in __clone (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x122102)

0x602000000074 is located 4 bytes inside of 8-byte region [0x602000000070,0x602000000078)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f5d176228df in operator delete(void*) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x1108df)
    #1 0x561fb617804f in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::thread>::deallocate(std::thread*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:128
    #2 0x561fb6176e45 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::thread> >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::thread>&, std::thread*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:470
    #3 0x561fb6175dbf in std::_Vector_base<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_deallocate(std::thread*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:351
    #4 0x561fb6177b78 in void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_realloc_insert<std::thread>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::thread*, std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> > >, std::thread&&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:500
    #5 0x561fb6176978 in void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<std::thread>(std::thread&&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:121
    #6 0x561fb6175355 in std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::push_back(std::thread&&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1201
    #7 0x561fb6172d26 in getFactorCount(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, int) /home/blackemr/cse381/exercise8_part2/exercise8_part2.cpp:53
    #8 0x561fb617397e in main /home/blackemr/cse381/exercise8_part2/exercise8_part2.cpp:126
    #9 0x7f5d171280b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f5d17621947 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10f947)
    #1 0x561fb617a66c in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::thread>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:114
    #2 0x561fb617985f in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::thread> >::allocate(std::allocator<std::thread>&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:444
    #3 0x561fb617876d in std::_Vector_base<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:343
    #4 0x561fb61778e7 in void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::_M_realloc_insert<std::thread>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::thread*, std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> > >, std::thread&&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:440
    #5 0x561fb6176978 in void std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::emplace_back<std::thread>(std::thread&&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:121
    #6 0x561fb6175355 in std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::push_back(std::thread&&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1201
    #7 0x561fb6172d26 in getFactorCount(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, int) /home/blackemr/cse381/exercise8_part2/exercise8_part2.cpp:53
    #8 0x561fb617397e in main /home/blackemr/cse381/exercise8_part2/exercise8_part2.cpp:126
    #9 0x7f5d171280b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

Thread T2 created by T0 here:
    #0 0x7f5d1754c805 in pthread_create (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x3a805)
    #1 0x7f5d173e4f78 in std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0xd6f78)
    #2 0x561fb6172d10 in getFactorCount(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, int) /home/blackemr/cse381/exercise8_part2/exercise8_part2.cpp:53
    #3 0x561fb617397e in main /home/blackemr/cse381/exercise8_part2/exercise8_part2.cpp:126
    #4 0x7f5d171280b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /home/blackemr/cse381/exercise8_part2/exercise8_part2.cpp:27 in thrMain(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fd fa fa 00 fa fa fa[fd]fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==4100441==ABORTING
```

I have tried changing the thread counter formula and my next idea is to use a mutex, is a mutex the correct way to prevent Race Conditions?

Comment: what does countFactors do?

Comment: Before I would spend too much time on it, I would confirm that the code ran on a single thread (though somewhat slower).

Comment: anyway , if you are sharing a vector beteen threads (not clear at all if thats what you are doing) then yes you need a mutex. Or you could provide a separate vector for each thread and merge the results at the end

Comment: I see some hints of writers and readers sharing data ... if that is so, yes, a mutex would be appropriate.

Comment: You don't need a mutex if the vectors are presized and the access (both read and write) to each element is exclusive to each thread. I.e. T1 never writes, nor reads, elements processed by T2, and vice versa. I think you would find this easier if you utilized an iterator-based solution rather than doing all the indexing you're doing.

Comment: Wait.. this is wrong. you're iterating over `numList.size()` items, each thread getting a partition window within that range. However, the loop that is doing `result[i] = countFactors(list[i]);` is storing results in a container that is `thrCount` in size. I.e. `countF` back in main. In short,`std::vector<int> countF(thrCount);` should be `std::vector<int> countF(theList.size());` (and btw, i noticed this while translating this to an iterator-based solution, because that size mismatch stuck out like a sore thumb).

Comment: @WhozCraig good catch

Comment: The array index calculations are completely broken. If you print out all the values of `startInd`, `endInd`, and `result.size()` you will discover that not only many of them make no sense whatsoever (with the starting index being greater than the ending index), but even the starting index is less than the ending index (so the loop in thread function will iterate at least once), it will still exceed `result.size()` at least some of the time, resulting in memory corruption, undefined behavior, and valgrind barking non-stop.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, that was the main problem, thank you for the correction.